# MySQL sum up a column and group by two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with the structure below:

```
Product       | Status        | Quantity
____________________________________________

P001          | 1             | 50
P001          | 1             | 30
P001          | 2             | 40
P001          | 2             | 60
```

I would like to sum the quantity which group by Product and Status.
The result will be:

```
Product       | Status 1 QTY   | Status 2 QTY
____________________________________________

P001          | 80             | 100
```

Can the above be done in ONE sql query?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

It can be done through `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT Product,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) `Status 1 QTY`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 2 THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) `Status 2 QTY`
FROM   TableName
GROUP  BY Product
```

If you have unknown number of values for `Status`, better do it dynamically.